# Evaporation of acetic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I performed aan acid catalysed haloform reaction in acetic acid to an acid. I need to evaporate acetic acid which I used as solvent and It is around 150 ml. What are the alternatives , I have a rotavap in lab but 150ml AA is too much for a rotavap I guess.

Comment: Are you evapotating to dryness? Don't worry about alternatives - use the rotavap with a not too small wide-neck (NS29) flask.

Comment: Alternative: destillation followed by neutralisation/extraction. I used that to remove propionic acid (whose boiling point is a lot worse for rotavaps than acetic acid’s) from my porphyrin condensation.

Comment: Rotavap is fine even until > 500 mL volume.